# No puedo lanzar un proyecto Angular

Tags: nodejs, angular

Tengo instalado angularCli 7 y nodejs 18

y al hacer ng serve me salta el siguiente error:

```
(node:16028) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
 10% building 4/5 modules 1 active ...t\index.js?http://0.0.0.0:0/sockjs-nodenode:internal/crypto/hash:69
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\acarrion\Desktop\TestingBase-master\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\acarrion\Desktop\TestingBase-master\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:401:16)
    at C:\Users\acarrion\Desktop\TestingBase-master\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:433:10
    at C:\Users\acarrion\Desktop\TestingBase-master\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:308:13
    at C:\Users\acarrion\Desktop\TestingBase-master\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\Users\acarrion\Desktop\TestingBase-master\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:203:19
    at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (C:\Users\acarrion\Desktop\TestingBase-master\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:43:13)
    at processResource (C:\Users\acarrion\Desktop\TestingBase-master\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:202:11)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\Users\acarrion\Desktop\TestingBase-master\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:158:10)
    at runLoaders (C:\Users\acarrion\Desktop\TestingBase-master\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (C:\Users\acarrion\Desktop\TestingBase-master\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:280:3)
    at NormalModule.build (C:\Users\acarrion\Desktop\TestingBase-master\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:427:15)
    at Compilation.buildModule (C:\Users\acarrion\Desktop\TestingBase-master\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:635:10)
    at C:\Users\acarrion\Desktop\TestingBase-master\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:884:14 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

El package.json del proyecto es este

https://github.com/MISW-4104-Web/TestingBase/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Lo que tienes instalado es una barbaridad. De todas maneras, una simple búsqueda en google de "angular 7 node" te muestra esta página: https://angular.io/guide/versions donde verás que para angular 7 necesitas node 8!! Por cierto, que angular 7 está súper, súper desactualizado. Estás intentando usar una versión de angular que data de la época de los dinosaurios (no literalmente, pero vaya)

Comment: Escribe en tu terminal `ng version` y pégala acá por favor